# In concourse how do you hijack a container made via `fly execute`

Tags: concourse

If you run `fly execute` to perform a one-off build, how can I then hijack/intercept the container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you perform a `fly execute` it gives you back a global build ID, which you can then use as an argument to `fly intercept`

```
$ fly -t ci e -c ci/build-docs.yml
executing build 43627
...

$ fly -t ci i -b 43627
bash-4.4#
```

Comment: It just says `no containers matched your search parameters!` and this is only seconds after it finsihed. How am I supposed to intercept it if it just disapears right away :-(